# Spring: autowire bean with same type as existing class

Tags: spring

After following some study trails and tutorials about Spring I still sometimes struggle to do things in the most elegant way.

I our project I need to configure a RestTemplate object to handle a GregorianCalendar by printing the date in the desired format in the Json post body, as well log the content of the post body to the logfiles.

I see no need to create a subclass here, it can just be done by setting existing properties to custom values, for which some other beans are created.

No issues with this code, but how to inject it in the class where I want to use it? When I use @Autowired, I need to specifiy a Qualifier to distinguish between the framework RestTemplate class and my customized one. 
Or can I just inject the bean using its id value, which is the name of the method here, so setuRestTemplate in my case?
Probably there is an easier way to inject this bean by name but I do not know what is the prefefred way to do it.

```
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;
//more imports

@Configuration
public class SixdegreesAppContext {


@Bean
public RestTemplate setuRestTemplate() {

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setMessageConverters(getSetuMessageConverters());

    //enable logging of post body
    ClientHttpRequestInterceptor loggingRequestInterceptor = new LoggingRequestInterceptor();
    List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> ris = new ArrayList<>();
    ris.add(loggingRequestInterceptor);

    restTemplate.setInterceptors(ris);
    restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory())); //no sure why this is needed

    return restTemplate;
}

@Bean
public List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> getSetuMessageConverters() {
    List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters = new ArrayList<>();
    MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jackson2HttpMessageConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    jackson2HttpMessageConverter.setObjectMapper(getSetuObjectMapper());
    converters.add(jackson2HttpMessageConverter);
    return converters;
}

@Bean
public ObjectMapper getSetuObjectMapper() {
    ObjectMapper jacksonObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
    module.addSerializer(XMLGregorianCalendar.class, new XmlGregorianCalendarSerializer());
    jacksonObjectMapper.registerModule(module);
    return jacksonObjectMapper;
}


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just name your bean as following:

```
public final static String REST_TEMPLATE_BEAN_NAME = "myRestTemplate";
@Bean(name = {REST_TEMPLATE_BEAN_NAME})
public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
    //...
    return new CustomizeRestTemplate();
}
```

Then you can refer it as following:

```
@Resource(name = REST_TEMPLATE_BEAN_NAME)
RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

Please remember, `REST_TEMPLATE_BEAN_NAME` is the static field you defined earlier. Is this what you want?

Comment: And of course, you can name it by defining a static String member field and refering them as you want, which will keep them consisitent.

Comment: THanks for your reply, the @Resource annotation is probably something I can use. I thought the name attribute is not really needed because the method name already acts as id.

Comment: Yes, you are right. If you want you can use its implictly identity. But it's could be misleading. However, both could work. Enjoy yourself.